# Does HTTP DELETE invalidate sub-URIs?

Tags: rest, http

Suppose I send the following sequence of HTTP requests

```
GET /charts/chart1.png

DELETE /charts

PUT /data/spreadsheet.csv

POST /charts

GET /charts/chart1.png
```

(The intention here is that a POST request to /charts regenerates the charts based on the uploaded data, but this doesn't really matter for the purposes of the question.)

According to rfc2616,

> Some HTTP methods MUST cause a cache to invalidate an entity. This is
> either the entity referred to by the Request-URI, or by the Location
> or Content-Location headers (if present). These methods are:
>
> - PUT
> - DELETE
> - POST

What this appears to say, at least literally, is that the DELETE and POST will invalidate the exact URI `/chart` but not any URI "contained under it," such as `chart/chart1.png`

If this is the case, it moreover seems like if you want to create a compliant REST API where a user can delete and regenerate a directory of files, you have to require that the user send individual DELETE requests for every single file in the directory in order to invalidate them before deleting and regenerating the directory.  And if we imagine there's a ton of stuff in that directory, this can end up being a pretty expensive operation.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something here?

Maybe.

The semantics of HTTP DELETE (currently described by [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-delete)) apply only to the target resource.

Web servers are, of course, entitled to remove any resources at any time, which of course includes removing multiple resources in response to an HTTP request.

So a "cascade delete" on the server is completely in bounds.

---

However, what we don't have is a general purpose mechanism for a server to describe an *arbitrary* collection of resource identifiers that should be invalidated by the request.  The rules for invalidating cached responses are described by [RFC 9111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-invalidating-stored-respons)

> A cache MUST invalidate the target URI...
>
> A cache MAY invalidate other URIs when it receives a non-error status
> code in response to an unsafe request method (including methods whose
> safety is unknown). In particular, the URI(s) in the Location and
> Content-Location response header fields (if present) are candidates
> for invalidation; other URIs might be discovered through mechanisms
> not specified in this document.

Note that the RFC2119:MAY here replaces the RFC2119:MUST that was present in earlier versions of the specification.

"mechanisms not specified in this document" would include ideas like [Linked Cache Invalidation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-linked-cache-inv-04), an idea that was abandoned when the draft expired in 2013, as far as I have been able to determine.

I haven't found an standardized alternative.